# Как отсортировать данные dataframe по количеству одинаковых записей?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть dataframe следующего вида:

```
id Name     Sex
0  Jack     male
1  Andrew   male
2  Andrew   female
3  Jack     male
4  Yuriy    male
5  Johanna  female
```

Необходимо получить самое часто используемое женское/мужское имя. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Group by pandas dataframe and select most common string factor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15222754/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы напечатать самые часто встречающиеся женское и мужское имена:

```
for sex in ['male', 'female']:
    print(df.loc[df.Sex==sex, 'Name'].value_counts(sort=False).idxmax())
```

Результат:

```
Jack
Andrew
```

Или как одно выражение:

```
>>> df.groupby('Sex').agg(lambda g: g.value_counts(sort=False).idxmax()))
          Name
Sex           
female  Andrew
male      Jack
```

Или явно выбирая имена:

```
>>> top_names = df.groupby('Sex')['Name'].agg(lambda g: g.value_counts(sort=False).idxmax())
>>> top_names.to_dict()
{'female': 'Andrew', 'male': 'Jack'}
```

Comment: @MaxU верно, ответ по ссылке, которую я привёл, `index[0]` использует. Это менее читаемо, поэтому явный idxmax() использую после value_counts() (это не ухудшает О-большое решения)¶ Если будет нужда константы улучшить  во временной сложности, тогда можно будет прикручивать. Если profiler покажет, что это узкое место в программе.

Answer (score 2):

`Series.value_counts()` возвращает количество вхождений для каждого значения в виде отсортированной по убыванию кол-ва вхождений серии, поэтому вызов `.idxmax()` - это ненужный расход ресурсов.

Пример:

```
In [50]: df.groupby('Sex')['Name'].agg(lambda g: g.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index(name='Most_popular_name')
Out[50]:
      Sex Most_popular_name
0  female           Johanna
1    male              Jack

In [51]: df.groupby('Sex')['Name'].agg(lambda g: g.value_counts().index[0]).to_dict()
Out[51]: {'female': 'Johanna', 'male': 'Jack'}
```

Comment: сортировка (O(n log n)) не нужна, max можно за линейное время найти.

Comment: @jfs, без сортировки выглядит лучше. Можно ещё и при группировке отказаться от сортировки

Comment: ваш ответ использует сортировку (это мелочь, но раз вы эту тему сами подняли (о производительности), то тогда адекватные решения, следует предлагать—без измерений не берусь сказать какой вариант быстрее для конкретного ввода)